# How to Put a Drawer on the Header

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to put a Drawer in the Header but it does not appear, how can I do it?

This is my Header code.

```
class Programs extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Header('Bem-Vindo',),(...)),),),),);}}
```

Header()

```
    class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget rightSide;
  Header(this.title, {this.rightSide});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(this.title,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28,color: Colors.grey[600],fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,),),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),height: 54.0,),
        (this.rightSide != null) ? this.rightSide : Container()],);}}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: on pressing which button do you want to open drawer?

Comment: Hi @Ana Cunha, can you please share what is the desired output you want? A screenshot or picture of UI.